# Is it possible to use map/filter/reduce inside a promise by returning the result with Promise.resolve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

What I'm currently doing to do loops inside a promise is as follows:

```
asyncFunc()
.then(() => {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
        for (let i = 0;  i < length; i++) {
        // do something
            if (j == length - 1) {
                return resolve(result);
            }
        }
    })
.then((result) => {
    console.log("This shows after the loop above is done");
    console.log(result);
});
```

I'm thinking of replacing this in a more concise manner by using map/filter/reduce by instead replacing the for loop with this:

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let result = some_list.filter((item) => {
        return item.count > 2;
    })
    return resolve(result);
})
```

Is this feasible? Or should I stick with using the for loop instead?

I've recently read articles on mixing synchronous code and asynchronous code, but haven't found a resolution to what to do with mixing them with promises.

Comment: yes it is possible.Also you can check consoling the output from both the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's perfectly reasonable code to have. You could even write it as:

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(some_list.filter((item) => {
        return item.count > 2;
    }));
});
```

Comment: or not promisify a synchronous operation inside `.then` in the first place (if you want to do things correctly, that is)

Answer (score 1):

You're promisifying synchronous code inside a .then ... there's really no need for that at all, since the value returned from a `.then` callback (i.e., your code) is always guaranteed to be a Promise

or, in other words, the value returned in `.then` is already made into a Promise, so creating a Promise for a value generated by synchronous code is redundant

so: your code is more correctly written

```
asyncFunc()
.then(() => some_list.filter(item => item.count > 2))
}).then((result) => {
    console.log("This shows after the loop above is done");
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Oh ok! So if I use map/filter/reduce I can just do that, but if I use a for loop I would need to use Promise.resolve right?

But what about if what's inside the `then` is multi-line? For example maybe two calls to filter or something else. Could I still guarantee that the last line, assuming that the `filter` example you've shown is the last line, would be the one returned to the next `then`?